# GAE DATASTORE select __KEY__

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I do the following query to fetch the **KEY**, I get null. Following is the query:

```
g_keys = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __KEY__ FROM greeting")
```

Here are the entities in Greeting DB Object:

```
Key Write Ops      ID   Key Name author comment     date            source
aglkZXZ-...  11    11  None      None   COMMENT1    2013-02-16      twitter
glkZXZ-...   11    12  None      None   COMMENT2    2013-02-17      facebook
```

and here is the model definition:

```
class Greeting(db.Model):

  author = db.UserProperty()
  comment = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  source = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For key only queries you have to use the key_only argument.

```
g_keys = Greeting.all(keys_only=True)
```

By the way : in your query you use greeting, but your model name is Greeting

Comment: Thanks. The typo was not in the code. But the issue is even when I use the construct that you have provided, I still get only nulls. Is there anything else that is required for me to ensure that I get the keys? Here is the result of the fetch when I used your construct [{"type": "Greeting", "id": null}, {"type": "Greeting", "id": null}]} (the same as doing GQLQuery of Keys).

Comment: What are you doing to get `[{"type": "Greeting", "id": null}, {"type": "Greeting", "id": null}]`  It would appear you are getting keys back, given you are getting a value for you type - which I assume you are using key.kind() to get.

Comment: Hi Tim, Not sure if I understand. The IDs are system generated, and as shown above I expect the ID to return 11 and 12 (as seen from ah_admin screen). But when I fetch it in the program they are returned as nulls. Please help!

Comment: My question was how are generating the string `[{"type": "Greeting", "id": null}, {"type": "Greeting", "id": null}]` in your question as this is not something your would get directly from any db api call.  If you are iterating over keys then the output of that is probably the problem as keys from the datastore can't exist without the id be it a name or integer.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am obtaining the above when I pass the keys as JSON object to the client and I am printing on client [{"type": "Greeting", "id": null}, {"type": "Greeting", "id": null}] . I am testing locally so cannot use GAE debug statements. Hope I answered your question. I appreciate your help, and hope I will be able to resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks Tim. You are right. It is the JSON object that is returning null. Not sure why... I will look into  it. But the encoder was provided by Google. Thanks a mil

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
__key__ (lowercase)
```

An example from here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference?hl=en

```
SELECT __key__ FROM Person WHERE age = NULL
```